# Filling a data.frame with values. How to speed up the process?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to fill an empty data.frame with values that are in another data.frame. At first I intialise an empty data.frame with the corresponding dimensions and then I use a for-loop to fill this data.frame with the values, which are contained in another data.frame. Is there a way to use an apply-type-function to speed up the process?

Thanks in advance,
BenR

**Update 2:** Fixed example.

```
set.seed(8760)
k <- c(rep(1:4, each = 6))
i <- paste(rep(LETTERS[1:6], times=4))
value <- sample(1:10000, 24)

input <- data.frame(k, i, value)

u_n <- unique(input$i)
id <- unique(input$k)

#' doConversion
#' 
#' Converts a dataset from original gdx version to more readable version.
#' 
#' @param x dataframe containing results of reporting.gms (sum_generation_parameter).
#' @return dataframe with EU-aggregated generation
#' @author BenR
doConversion <- function(x){
  stopifnot(class(x) %in% c("data.frame","matrix") &
              names(x) == c("k","i","value"))

  # get technology name and temporal id
  u_n <- unique(x$i)
  id <- unique(x$k)

  # initialise data.frame containing all zeros and the right names
  nodata <- data.frame(setNames(replicate(length(u_n),numeric(length(id)), simplify = F), u_n))
  data <- cbind(id, nodata)

  # assign values to particular entries of the data.frame
  for (i in colnames(data[, 2:ncol(data)])){
    for (j in id){
      if(length(rownames(x[which(x$i == i & x$k == j) , ])==0)){
        help <- x[which(x$i == i & x$k == j), "value"]
        data[which(data$id == j) ,i ] <- help
      }
    }
  }
  return(data)
}

r <- doConversion(input)
```

Comment: Provide example input and show and explain expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion/proposal. I updated my question.

Comment: Now explain what your code is supposed to achieve. (Your aim is not filling a matrix with values.)

Comment: Thanks again. There is another update the hopefully clears things up.

Comment: You code doesn't run with your input. `doConversion(input)` returns an error. Just show the expected output. However, I suspect you want to do an operation that is called "reshaping" in R. If that's the case, there is a package reshape2 that might be of interest to you. Also, your example input is in the perfect shape for creating "diagrams or other things".

Comment: Hey, I am really sorry for the broken example and very thankful for you trying to help me. I fixed it. And I guess you might be right with regards to the reshape package... Unfortunately, before creating a diagram I need to perform another action on my data. This is why I need to transform it in the desired way.

Comment: Is there a way to sum over the values, where id takes a certain value?

Comment: Sure. Google for "R split-apply-combine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function:

```
doConversion(input)
#  id    A    B    C    D    E    F
#1  1 6947 6344 6291 2182 5430 9555
#2  2 2758 4375 7649 3096 8325 1109
#3  3 6073  168 2265 8739 6293 9003
#4  4 6278 1994 8597  332 2716 6504
```

Using the reshape2 package:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(input, k ~ i)
#  k    A    B    C    D    E    F
#1 1 6947 6344 6291 2182 5430 9555
#2 2 2758 4375 7649 3096 8325 1109
#3 3 6073  168 2265 8739 6293 9003
#4 4 6278 1994 8597  332 2716 6504
```

However, as I said in the comments, the long format of your input is usually better suited for data processing in R.

Comment: I am rather new to R so thank you very much for the help! This opened up my eyes...